# Merge several google analytic accounts into 1 account with several profiles

Tags: google-analytics, google-apps

So basically i've created several new google analytic accounts (under the same google account login) that really should have been under the same analytic account.

```
**For Example**
I've created:

Account 1
UA-12345678-1

Account 2
UA-12345678-2

Account 3
UA-12345678-3

**And I want**
Account
Profile 1: UA-12345678-1
Profile 2: UA-12345678-2
Profile 3: UA-12345678-3
```

Is there anyway to make merge accounts into profiles without losing any data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does not look like this is possible:

> It is not possible to merge accounts or transfer data between accounts. You can export the data from your Google Analytics accounts and use third party tools.

[Is it possible to merge data for a domain from to accounts?](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Google+Analytics/thread?tid=1501510ebcfa26a5&hl=en)

Answer (score 1):

You already have just ONE account, because GA considers the '12345678' the ACCOUNT and the -1 or -2 etc... is considered a 'Property'.

However, that's just syntax. I think what you're trying to do is to view data across these three different 'Properties' in one - which you cannot do. However, you COULD track all three properties. If you track all three properties all of the time, you might as well just delete the other two and just use one. But if e.g. you have a main site 12345678-1 and a related microsite (e.g. a blog or events site) 12345678-2 you could add the main site tracker to the microsite as well, but not add the microsite tracker to the main site. I.e. track -1 on all pages, track -2 only on the microsite, and track -3 on the main site only. So in GA you have ALL data in -1 (and you can set up advanced segments or custom reports to do comparisons), you use the -2 and the -3 account to have separate data.

Hope that helps.